# Correlation between two variables with non-linear relationship

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, nonlinear

Suppose I have two variables x and y. x and y have a non-linear relationship. However, they always move in the same direction. In other words, when x goes up, y goes up. When x goes down, y goes down.

Is it correct to say that the correlation between x and y will surely be positive, although the correlation value is unlikely to be near 1 because they have a non-linear relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> they always move in the same direction. In other words, when x goes up, y goes up. When x goes down, y goes down.

i.e. their relationship is *monotonic* (specifically, monotonic increasing).

> Is it correct to say that the correlation between x and y will surely be positive

For a perfectly monotonic relationship, the *linear* correlation will be positive, though it may be arbitrarily close to 0. (I presume you specifically intend the Pearson correlation coefficient.)

Some other measures of correlation -- specifically ones which pick up monotonic relationships, like the Kendall and Spearman correlation coefficients -- will be 1.